# How to represent cluster nodes with multiple parents

Tags: d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, diagram

I am trying to visualise the businesses in a particular market. I've been looking at the d3 documentation and Mike Bostock's brilliant site http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock . I'm completely new to data visualisation so haven't got a deep understanding of the terms yet but I find it fascinating and I'm learning fast! I'm not looking for a solution but rather some pointers so that I can find/write the code.

Here are the parameters of the problem:

- the market has 3 functions; design, build and maintenance
- roughly 50 companies
- some companies supply just one function and others supply multiple

I would like to create a collapsible cluster (?) which initially shows only 3 nodes (representing the functions) with size relative to the number of children in each node. When one of the nodes is clicked it shows something like the zoomable circle packing diagram http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607535 showing the companies in each function. This is all straight forward and I could build it using Mike's examples (thank you).

However, what should I do where a company delivers 2 functions?
Should I duplicate the company into the different nodes (doesn't feel right to have more than one instance of a company)?

I get the feeling I'm using the wrong type of diagram but without knowing the terminology I'm struggling to know what to look for.

I appreciate this is noob question but any advice/pointers about what to look for would be great.

Many thanks, James

Comment: What do you want to show with the diagram?

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff initially, I'd like to simply show the relative competition within each of the functions (e.g. building has x2 the number of companies in maintenance etc). Then I'd like to be able to show the specific companies competing in each function to uncover the "oh I didn't realise company X did maintenance too" reaction. This might also uncover common combinations (e.g. lots of companies do design and build but none does design and maintenance). Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, you could do something like a [collapsible force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130) where you show three nodes for the sectors initially and then the companies as new nodes which can be connected to more than one sector.

Comment: Thanks for your advice @LarsKotthoff . I think I'll try to combine a collapsible force layout with nodes that change in size depending how many children they have. When the nodes are clicked I'll display a circle packing diagram to display the companies. I guess it should be possible :-)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff the collapsible force layout does not support multiple parents.

Comment: @DaoLam You would need to duplicate the nodes that have more than one parent (once for each parent) and then e.g. connect them to show that they belong together.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Sorry I'm not sure what you meant by that. Wouldn't we have duplicated nodes? For example, this image shows 2 "graph". I want "graph" to be a child of "flare" and "analytics" at the same time. http://imgur.com/YlNJ8Ld

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean -- you would have duplicated nodes.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Any solutions that would help showing it as a DAG and still enable collapsible?

Comment: @DaoLam Not that I'm aware of.